# How to simulate a terminal-like behaviour of a "chat-bot" program?

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C and this is also my first post on StackOverflow.

I am currently trying to build a "bot"-like behaviour on C that reads and writes in stdin. I would like it to behave similar to a terminal. I am having a few issues when reading some values from the input stream: (**In both cases, the expected input to scan is an int**)

1st issue - The username is written on the stream as many times as I type in non-integer characters (terminal below)

```
Me> s
Me> sss
Me> Me> Me> s
Me> ssss
Me> Me> Me> Me> a
Me> fs
Me> Me>
```

2nd issue - When I hit enter without having typed anything, the username is not displayed (terminal below):

```
Me> s
Me> s
Me> 

1
-------
Bot> OK
```

The code is something similar to this behaviour:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int val;
    printf("Bot> Enter an int\n");
    do {
        printf("Me> ");
        scanf("%d", &val);
    } while(getchar() != '\n');
    printf("Bot> OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to make my program as strong as possible and as user-friendly as possible (I tried using getchar() in scanf's to prevent the program from entering and infinite loop, but it didn't solve any of the problems above.) Would you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Start by *always* checking `scanf()`'s return value to see if it succeeded or not. Or better yet, never using it.

Comment: With "never using it", Shawn probably means more or less what is described in this very helpful text: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you for the link. I will read it thoroughly before moving on.

Comment: Exactly, it is for knowing, not necessarily for following in all situations. And my pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%d` format for `scanf` will automatically eat and discard leading white-space (like newlines).

For `scanf` to be able to tell if there was some input it must be able to see the first *non* space character. If it's all just spaces (like newline) then `scanf` won't return.

Also relevant is that if `scanf` fails to match the format string, then it will leave the input buffer alone. So if the first character was a non-digit character, then `scanf` will return immediately, and the next time you call an input function that exact character will be read.

I recommend you read whole lines using [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead, and then attempt to parse that line. If you use `sscanf` to parse the string, then always check what it [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
int main(void) {
    int val;
    printf("Bot> Enter an int\n");
    do {
        printf("Me> "); /* (A) */
        scanf("%d", &val); /* (B) */
    } while(getchar() != '\n');
    return 0;
}
```

The first issue is caused as the line labeled (B) will only read **one** non-integer character each time (and will put its ASCII value into `val`). Therefore the number of chars you inputted is the number of times your program will cycle between (A) - (B) - (A). Since the user did not hit enter, nor did your program prints it using a `printf("\n");`, when cycling between (A) and (B), all `"Me> "` get printed on the same line.

The second issues is caused as `scanf()` won't return if you do not input anything. So on this sample output you provided,

```
Me> s
Me> s
Me> 
                    /* (C) */
1
-------
Bot> OK
```

On line (C), `scanf()` had not returned yet. It is still reading your input and your code is still at line (B), not yet cycled to line (A), hence no output `"Me> "`.

It looks like that you want to print one and only one `"Me> "` each time user hits `enter`. If so, try to use `getline()`, and then use `sscanf()` to process the input.